# Button must be tapped twice to go next view when using shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, segue

I got some troubles when i want to go from my login-view to the main-view of my application. The problem is that i must tap the login-button twice before the next view shows.

When i debug the function, the Loginbool return false at the first click, but on the second click, it returns true, and i have no idea why.

Here is my shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    //Check if there is some data in keychain
    if(emailText != nil && passwordText != nil && accountText != nil && identifier == "nextViewInstantly")
    {
        return true
    }

    let segueShouldOccur = checkIfFilled()

    if(segueShouldOccur == false)
    {
        let ServerResponse = ServerResponseHandler()
        ServerResponse.message("All fields are required", title: "Sign in failed")
    }

    if(identifier == "nextView" && segueShouldOccur == true)
    {
        TryLogin()
    }

    if(Loginbool == 1)
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We're missing much of the code to see what's really happening. But my guess would be that your TryLogin method is asynchronous, so LoginBool is checked before the actual login is done.

What you should do :

On button press, check the data validity/presence, if the data is valid, perform a login, when the login is successful, performSegue to go to the next view controller. If the login is unsuccessful, display an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prepareforsegue` to send some data to next viewcontroller. this method get called just before performing segue.

You should call login web service on login button click and you should perform segue from completion handler or success block of web service call.

So when ypu got acknowledgement from server that user is valid you can go to next view controller.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
}
```